# Redux with Nextjs - Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am fetching to get data from the server before the app is rendered, by store that `data` into the redux store.

And facing this error:

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a

in `_app.tsx`:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, data }: AppProps & { data: any }) {
  console.log(data); // data is here

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Dispatch an action to store the fetched data in Redux store
    dispatch(saveData(data));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
  const data = await fetch(`http://base-url/my-route`).then((res) => res.json());

  let pageProps = {};

  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
  }

  return { pageProps, data };
};

export default MyApp;
```

store is exported from store.ts, and I am able to use those useDispatch and useSelector well in other parts of the app.

Comment: I think using `useDispatch` and `dispatch` inside `_app.tsx` will not work because the `_app.tsx` is the one who is `providing` in `store` and does not have access to the store. Meaninig, only the components INSIDE the `<Provider />` have access to the store and can dispatch the actions. Which is not the case in `_app.tsx`. So, I thing thats the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `useDispatch` outside the [`Provider`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider).

You can use `useDispatch` inside your `Component`, but not in `MyApp`,
because `Component` is inside the `Provider` with the connected `store`, but `MyApp` is not:

```
function MyApp() {

  // -- here is outside the Provider (no useDispatch possible) --

    return (
        <Provider store={ store }>
            {/* -- here is inside the provider -- */}
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

There are 3 solutions:

1. Add the data during the creation of the initial `store` object
2. Use the `store` object directly (without `useDispatch`)
3. Create a `Loader` component, which can use `useDispatch`

#### 1. Add the data during the creation of the initial `store` object

You surely have code to create the store somewhere, e.g.:

```
const myStore = createStore( myReducer, myInitialState );
```

You might be able to create the initial state `myInitialState` with your data from
`getInitialProps` already included:

```
const myStore = useMemo(() => {
    const staticInitialState = {
        // your static state
    };
    
    const myInitialState = {
        ...staticInitialState,
        ...dataFromGetInitialProps
    }; 
    
    return createStore( reducer, myInitialState );
}, []);
```

I think this would be the cleanest solution, because it is exactly inline with both the React and the Redux concepts.

*(Apparently [`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/usage/configuring-your-store#the-solution-configurestore) is deprecated and there is a new, much more complicated
syntax with [`configureStore`](https://redux.js.org/usage/configuring-your-store#the-solution-configurestore) and `createSlice`, which I'm not yer familiar with.)*

#### 2. Use the `store` object directly

You can not use `useDispatch` inside `MyApp`, but you *do* have the `store` object available there.
The `store` object [has a `dispatch` and a `getState` method](https://redux.js.org/api/store#store-methods), which you can use, e.g.:

```
function MyApp() {

    console.log( store.getState() );

    useEffect(() => {
        store.dispatch( saveData( data ) );
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <Provider store={ store }>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

I think this is ok, but more like a "workaround" than a "solution", because using the `store` methods directly
seems a bit more *low level* than using the `Provider`, and probably intended for more advanced
use cases.

#### 3. Create a 'Loader' component

You can create a component inside the `Provider`, and put your `dispatch` logic there.
Alternatively you could create a Wrapper [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)
around the `Component`, if more appropriate.

```
function DataLoader({ data }){

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect( () => {
        dispatch( saveData( data ) );
    }, [] );

    return null;
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, data }){
    return (
        <Provider store={ store }>
            <DataLoader data={ data } />
            <Component { ...pageProps } />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

This seems pretty hacky to me, because is (mis-)uses a component as a kind of "life cycle hook",
and there is no logical relation between the `DataLoader` and the location where it is put inside
the code (it could really be anywhere, as long as the component is rendered at the right time).